# exclude one of the hue from seaborn catplot visualization

Tags: seaborn, hue, catplot

I want to visualize category count by seaborn catplot but one of the hue are not important and don't need to include the visualization.
How can I select specific Hues at catplot to visualize without changing or removing any value from the column ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the rows with that value from the dataframe.  If the column is `Categorical` you might also need to change the categories as the legend will still contain all the categories.

Here is an example:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
tips['day'].dtype # CategoricalDtype(categories=['Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'], ordered=False)
# create a subset, a copy is needed to be able to change the categorical column
tips_weekend = tips[tips['day'].isin(['Sat', 'Sun'])].copy()
tips_weekend['day'].dtype # CategoricalDtype(categories=['Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'], ordered=False)
tips_weekend['day'] = pd.Categorical(tips_weekend['day'], ['Sat', 'Sun'])
tips_weekend['day'].dtype # CategoricalDtype(categories=['Sat', 'Sun'], ordered=False)
sns.catplot(data=tips_weekend, x='smoker', y='tip', hue='day')
```

[image: catplot with reduced hue levels]

For the follow-up question, a `histplot` with `multiple='fill'` can show the percentage distribution:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
tips_weekend = tips.copy()
tips_weekend['day'] = tips_weekend['day'].apply(lambda x: x if x in ['Sat', 'Sun'] else 'other')
# fix a new order
tips_weekend['day'] = pd.Categorical(tips_weekend['day'], ['other', 'Sat', 'Sun'])

ax = sns.histplot(data=tips_weekend, x='smoker', hue='day', stat='count', multiple='fill',
                  palette=['none', 'turquoise', 'crimson'])
# remove the first label ('other') in the legend
ax.legend(handles=ax.legend_.legendHandles[1:], labels=['Sat', 'Sun'], title='day')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
# add percentages
for bar_group in ax.containers[:-1]:
    ax.bar_label(bar_group, label_type='center', labels=[f'{bar.get_height() * 100:.1f} %' for bar in bar_group])
```

[image: seaborn showing percentage distribution]

Comment: As followup question ,If we remove other days How can you demonstrate how many percent of total weekdays as Yes or No are Sat and Sun?

Comment: Thank you for reply In this case we have Sat ,Sun and Other days as [Mon,Tue,Wed,Thursday,Friday] Total Sat and Sun are not 100% as we have other days but we don't want to visualize others percentage and only need percentages for Saturday and Sunday .

Comment: @SA_H Have you been able to find a solution?